# Add polyfill to Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

Is there a way within an Angular CLI project to have a library provide a polyfill? Within `angular.json`, the main app is by default configured with `"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts"`. This option is not available for a library project.

My specific use case is that my library has a dependency that requires a polyfill. Without the ability of the library automatically providing the polyfill upon it being imported in an application, I need to document and inform the library user of adding the polyfill themselves.

Comment: I created a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12652) on the Angular CLI repo. Let's see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Seems like they are never going to implement something like that, for everybody looking for this.

Comment: @SamHerrmann can you close this ticket, since the Feature request is closed , there is no point for this ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Jeba Prince, I have closed this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This capability is not available in the CLI and it will not become available for good reasons. The following is [A. Agius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695438/a-agius)' comment on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12652#issuecomment-431405583) that I had created to enquire about this feature:

> IMHO, a library should never bundle a polyfill. It’s up to the
>   consumers of the library based on their targeted browsers to include a
>   polyfill or not.
>
> If I want to target only ever green browsers I certainly don’t want
>   that a library that I am using has an embedded polyfill.
>
> As an application develop, I don’t want to end up having duplicate
>   polyfills for the same thing, because it was already shipped in
>   library that I am using.